# Length in bytes of text with (CR) (LF)

Tags: tcl

I’ve got from sqlite3 value that could be written in hex like "0x0D 0x0A". Yes, it’s (CR) and (LF). I want to know a length of data i’ve got. But command "string length" returns 1, not 2. "string bytelength" returns 1 too. How can I get correct length of data in bytes?

It’s a simple example. In real program I’ve got different text data from sqlite with unknown encoding. All I need is to get length of data in bytes. But every (CR)(LF) in text are counting as 1 byte.
Examples of getting data from sqlite and file:

```
sqlite dbcmd messages.db
set t [dbcmd message from messages limit 1,1]
string length $t


set f [open test.txt r]
set t [read $f]
string length $t
```

(Windows 7, ActiveTcl 8.6.4, tclkit 8.6.6)

Comment: Don't use `string bytelength` unless you really want to know about the size of the storage required for a particular form of value at the C level. It's very rarely useful for anyone at the Tcl script level (I have code that actually uses it when issuing runtime-generated assembly code, but that's a really unusual use case indeed…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*By default,* Tcl transforms CR-LF sequences in files being read into simple LF characters. This is usually useful, as it simplifies ordinary text processing in scripts greatly. However, if want the exact values then you can use `fconfigure` to put the channel into an alternate processing mode. For example, changing the channel's `-translation` setting to `lf` (from `auto`) will make all carriage-returns be preserved (and line-feeds too).

```
set f [open test.txt r]
fconfigure $f -translation lf
set t [read $f]
string length $t
```

There are other settings that could — in general — affect what you get, particularly the `-eofchar` and `-encoding` options. The `-eofchar` is usually EOF (i.e., the character associated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and the `-encoding` is a system-specific value that depends on things like what your platform is and what your locale is. If you want to really work with binary data, i.e., get just the bytes, you can set the `-translation` option to `binary`, which sets everything up right for handling binary data. There's a shorthand for that common option in the `open` command:

```
set f [open test.txt rb];  # ««« “b” flag in open mode
set t [read $f]
string length $t
```

If you do get the bytes and want to get characters from them at some point, the `encoding convertfrom` command is the tool you'll need. Remember, **characters and bytes are *not* the same thing.** That had to be given up in order to allow people to use more characters than there are values expressible in a byte.

Comment: In my case i'm getting string from sqlite. It is neither file nor channel to configure. Is it saving to file the only way to get size in bytes of this string?

Comment: Did i understand you correctly, @DonalFellows? It is no difference if it was CR-LF or LF in sqlite, I'm always getting only LF in tcl. And when i'm writing to socket LF could become CR-LF or stay LF depends on socket `lf` configuration, can't it?

Comment: After detailed check I have found only LF in database. So, TCL getting data from sqlite with no transformation. If database stores CR-LR, TCL getting CR-LR, I’ve checked it out.
In my issue TCL transforms from LR to CR-LR when it writes to socket.

Comment: There's all sorts of places where transformations can occur, and network sockets are one of them (connected sockets can be `fconfigured` just like open files). Unfortunately, there's no real fix other than to be _exactly careful_ about what data you're really passing in particular places. You know… actually **defining** the protocol that you're using.